# Can we get $x^TAx>0$ on condtion that $A > 0$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Can we get $x^TAx>0$ on condtion that $A > 0$? Where $x\in R^n$, $A \in R^{n\times n}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $A > 0$?  Most often the statement $A > 0$ means that $x^T A x > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: That is the definition of a positive definite matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: @littleO Thank u! Actually I got confused by the condition that A > 0, I thought it may mean that $a_{ij}>0$.

Comment: @Oswin It might, depending on the context.